# How to make this plugin more efficient

Tags: rss

Hi I have this plugin

http://pastebin.com/a7t1SPXj

which imports feeds from various websites. There are two problems I would like help in solving. The first is that I would like to place a limit on the date of the oldest feeds retrieved, limiting all results to the last 7 days. Secondly when I add more than 10 feeds it really starts to slow down the page and gets me PHP timeout errors. How can I make it more efficient, so it doesn't require huge load times on every page load? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of checking and updating the feeds every time you do the shortcode, instead register cron tasks for each feed timed to their update schedule. Also saving the feed items as posts, and storing the GUID in the posts meta, then only saving the feed items that are new, will simplify things. It will also let you use WP_Query on posts instead of dealing with feed transients too.

Comment: Could you explain why a WP_Query is more efficient than fetch_feed?  fetch_feed uses get_transient which is a direct call to the database no query is run.

Comment: Because it can speed up the feed aggregation stage. If you cache anything with transients, it should be the final output, not the aggregated feed items. Right now your transients are being used as your timing mechanism, but mobing to cron makes the process asynchronous, and lets you break the task up into smaller tasks for each feed.

Comment: Thanks, I sort of get it, but not sure I have enough knowledge to implement it. Are there any examples I can follow to implement this?

Comment: You will need to look up http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_post and http://codex.wordpress.org/Category:WP-Cron_Functions

Comment: I would also store the html output as a transient rather than the feed data, as it makes re-rendering that part of the page much much faster

Comment: if you need help with cron tasks, search for 'wp cron' howtos, there are lots of tutorials

Comment: How can the html output be stored as a transient?

Comment: a transient holds a data value, html is data ( a string ), just pass in a variable containing the html

Comment: ok but how can I get the generated html?

Comment: That's kind of basic PHP. Instead of `?><p>hello world</p><?php` you can do `echo "<p>hello world</p>";`, just as you can do `$val = "<p>hello world</p>"; echo $val;`

Comment: Also look at PHP output buffers

Comment: "Also saving the feed items as posts, and storing the GUID in the posts meta, then only saving the feed items that are new" 

If I have a cron job that grabs all the feed URLs and then fetches the feed for each one of them, the next step would be to save them into the wp_posts table. Do I already have a GUID to compare at that point, or am I getting this wrong?

Comment: As I mentioned, saving the GUI or URL in the post meta gives you an easy method of checking if that URL has already been fetched. Just do a query for a post with that meta value, if none are found then it's new, if posts are found then you've already fetched it

Comment: As I understand the GUID is unique, so making a check before I insert into the database wouldn't work. Maybe I could make a check on the feed item's permalink instead. I still think I'm clear about it though :S

Comment: Say cron is set to check for new feed items every hour, for all feed sources at once.

Ideally if at all possible the system would check what feed items there are already in the wp_posts table, and when it goes to do the fetch_feed(), it brings in only newer posts.

If that's not possible I guess I'd have to fetch_feed() for all items, then before inserting each feed item into the wp_posts table, make a check on the permalink, if it is already found then the new item won't make it in and is discarded.

Comment: no no, add a post meta containing the source URL, then search for posts with that meta equal to the URL when testing if it's new or not. If no posts are found it;s new. If a post is found with a meta containing the URL, it's not new

Comment: Ok then it's the feed permalink that needs to be checked, the mentioning of GUID just threw me off track there, as that is only available AFTER a post is saved. Thanks.

Comment: @TomJNowell Where does one use output buffering and where do you use Transients instead?

Comment: Output buffers and transients are completely different concepts, and are as related as pumpkins and bridges